# Ef Core 3 linq to sql not returning included objects

Tags: c#

Ok this one is confusing me.  I'm trying to return objects with included linked objects, but it fails when I use a dto:

```c#
class MyObject1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public MyObject2 Mo2 { get; set }
    //Other properties
}

class MyObject2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}

class MyObject3
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MyIntValue { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}

class MyDTO
{
    public MyObject1 Mo1 { get; set; }
    public int MyIntValue { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the anonymous selector, i get the linked objects loaded:

```c#
void ThisWorks()
{
    var result = await
        (
            from mo1 in context.MyObject1s
                .Include(item => item.Mo2)

            //No nav-path or foriegn key setup, so do it the old fashioned way
            join mo3 in context.MyObject3s on mo1.Id equals mo3.Id into mo3s
            from mo3 in mo3s.DefaultIfEmpty()

            select new
            {
                mo1,
                myIntValue = mo3 == null ? 0 : mo3.MyIntValue
            }
        )
        .ToListAsync();


    bool success = result.Mo1.Mo2 != null;
    //result.Mo1.Mo2 is not null!
}
```

But when I try to use the Dto, it fails:

```c#
void ThisFails()
{
    var result = await
        (
            from mo1 in context.MyObject1s
                .Include(item => item.Mo2)

            //No nav-path or foriegn key setup, so do it the old fashioned way
            join mo3 in context.MyObject3s on mo1.Id equals mo3.Id into mo3s
            from mo3 in mo3s.DefaultIfEmpty()

            select new MyDto
            {
                Mo1 = mo1,
                MyIntValue = mo3 == null ? 0 : mo3.MyIntValue
            }
        )
        .ToListAsync();

    bool success = result.Mo1.Mo2 != null;
    //result.Mo1.Mo2 is null - Why? And how do I solve it?
}
```

Why does the linked object not load when I create a Dto? I'm using the query in a few different places, so I want to define it once, but I need a dto to hold the MyIntValue.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try converting it to SQL using LINQPAD or .ToTraceString() and see if that sheds any light.

Answer (score 0):

Include has no effect on projections.

You must create a separate property to hold the child entity:

```
class MyDTO
{
    public MyObject1 Mo1 { get; set; }
    public MyObject2 Mo2 { get; set; }
    public int MyIntValue { get; set; }
}
```

and project like this:

```
 select new MyDto
            {
                Mo1 = mo1,
                Mo2 = mo1.Mo2,
                MyIntValue = mo3 == null ? 0 : mo3.MyIntValue
            }
```

I would suggest to not hold entities inside your DTOs. Would be better to flatten the values, or create "child DTOs" (like Dto1 and Dto2 for each entity).